# "They had read, but none replied" or "they have read, but none replied"?

Tags: grammar, tense, past-perfect

> They had read, but none replied.
>
> They have read, but none replied.

Which one is correct?

---

Note: This originally had the second sentence be "they have read, but none replies."

Comment: You have two different variables. Are you asking about *had* versus *have* or about *replied* versus *replies*?

Comment: I didn't realize I typed that. I mean for the second sentence "they have read, but none replied" thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not a native speaker, but I think if you are saying that they have read your complaints but they never reply, you should say:

> They have read(RED) my complaints but none of them (ever) replies.

If you want to say that they have read your letter but have not replied as of now:

> They have read(RED) my complaints but none of them has replied.

If you are talking about past:

> They read(RED) my complaints but none of them replied.

If you are talking about something that has happened in past but want to talk about something that happened before that past:

> I was very sad.They had read(RED) my complaints,but none of them replied.